# Opening SSIS package crashing Visual Studio Professional 2017(Version 15.9.14)

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I have Visual studio Professional 2017(version 15.9.14) and I have installed SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual studio 2017(15.9.2). I am very new to SSIS packages. Most of the packages works fine for me but there are very few packages created by other team members whenever I tries to open those SSIS packages my visual studio crashes.

I researched online but haven't found much information about this issue. I restarted my computer multiple times but this does not solved the problem. I also uninstalled and installed SSDT again still does not solve the issue. My other team members have the same visual studio version and also they have same version of SSDT but they can open those packages it's only my visual studio that crashes whenever I open those packages.

Comment: What is the exception thrown?

Comment: it just crashes without any error. whenever I double click on package name it just crashes without any error.